# why is the setEnabled(false) not deactivating the button

Tags: android

I have used a (+/-)button to increment or decrement a counter but I hv set an upper limit 2 so I want to disable the plus button of the ElegantNumberbutton after the counter reaches two,and I want the minus button to stay active.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ElegantNumberButton numberbutton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    numberbutton=(ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.numberButton);
  //  counter=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counterTxt);



    numberbutton.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) {


            String count= numberbutton.getNumber();
            int temp=Integer.parseInt(count);
          if(temp>=2 ) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO more casual leave allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              numberbutton.setEnabled(false);



          }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you please add the xml as well

Comment: Why don't you directly use `newValue` instead of getting it by `numberbutton.getNumber()` which value may not be up to date?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [this](https://github.com/ashik94vc/ElegantNumberButton) by *ElegantNumberButton*, I would say that it is not really a button. It is a RelativeLayout, so its *setEnabled()* do not change any of the children inside it. For disable the +/- buttons, try the following code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numberbutton.getChildCount(); i++) {
   View child = numberbutton.getChildAt(i);
   child.setEnabled(false);
}
```